# Why we use for loop to add a method to an object Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I see in many JavaScript books that a `for` loop is used when we get a `Array` of objects and do something on it

```
function()  
  {  
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");  

    for (var i = 0, ii = links.length; i < ii; i++)  
    {  
      links[i].addEventListener("event", eventListener, false);  
    }  
}
```

Well, my question is why we use a `for` loop I mean why not we simply do something directly on that `Array`. Just like following code

```
function()  
  {  
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    links.addEventListener("event", eventListener, false);  
}
```

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Because `getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList not a single Node, so you need to loop. Have you tried your second example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns a nodeList object and that object does not contain a method `.addEventListener()` so what you are proposing will cause a script error.

What you need is the ability to add an event listener to each DOM object in the nodeList.  You can either use a `for` loop to iterate over the nodeList yourself or create your own function/method to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Because then you add the event-listener  to the array object instead of adding it to each one of its elements

Comment: And what happen when someone add the event-listener to the array object?

Comment: @Arya nothing really... :)